# What is the meaning of "a hell of a lot"?

Tags: meaning

I read [the following](http://www.elllo.org/english/0101/140-Jason-Art.htm),  but can not understand meaning of **a hell of a lot**:

> *Todd:* So when people go to your web site what can they see?
>   *Jason:* Not a hell of a lot but I did draw everything on there myself, every button every  single piece of graphic you see on there I drew, just photographs of me, my friends, drawings that I've done and posted up and not really much else, but it's good if you just want to check it out. Check some photos out.

Can any one explain it?

Comment: as @cornbread points out, it would be good if you could provide the sentence immediately preceding this one.

Comment: Any dictionary worth the name has the answer to this question. For example, [this one does](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85636#eid1683404). Voting to close as General Reference.

Comment: Or, if that link doesn't work, [this one does](http://www.dictionarist.com/hell+of+a+lot), too.

Comment: ELL! Please vote to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quoted text isn't formal, grammatical English, but the transcription of a flow of thoughts, so it is a little tricky to parse.

*Hell of a* (which you may see written as *helluva*) adds strong emphasis to a concept; it may be considered a mild profanity. *She's a hell of a sailor* means that she is an exceptional sailor. *Hell of a lot* means there is a large amount or a high degree of something. *The recipe uses a hell of a lot of sugar* means that the recipe calls for a great deal of sugar.

*Not a hell of a lot*, then, means that there is not a great deal or high degree of something. It could refer to something said previously. It could be a statement of modesty, that whatever being discussed is no big deal despite the work the writer seems to have put into it. It could mean something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

*A hell of a lot*, often seen as *a helluva lot* is a colorful way of expressing a great deal of *x*.

Examples:

- We went to a buffet for dinner and I had *a hell of a lot* of food.
- $30 trillion is *a hell of a lot* of money.

Whatever *x* your example refers to must have been given in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 0):

My dictionary says:

**a / one hell of a — —** (informal) used to emphasise something very bad or great: *it cost us a hell of a lot of money*